# r: regex for containing pattern with negation

Tags: r, regex

Suppose I have the following two strings and want to use `grep` to see which match:

```
business_metric_one
business_metric_one_dk
business_metric_one_none
business_metric_two
business_metric_two_dk
business_metric_two_none
```

And so on for various other metrics. I want to only match the first one of each group (`business_metric_one` and `business_metric_two` and so on). They are not in an ordered list so I can't index and have to use `grep`. At first I thought to do:

`.*metric.*[^_dk|^_none]$`

But this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the criterion here to exclude a value? If it ends with `_dk` or `_none`? But still contains `metric`?

Comment: There's an inclusion criterion (needs to include `metric` or some string), but it should fail if it includes either `_dk` or `_none`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a PCRE pattern to filter the character vector:

```
x <- c("business_metric_one","business_metric_one_dk","business_metric_one_none","business_metric_two","business_metric_two_dk","business_metric_two_none")
grep("metric(?!.*_(?:dk|none))", x, value=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "business_metric_one" "business_metric_two"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/JhpYgT)

The `metric(?!.*(?:_dk|_none))` pattern matches

- `metric`  - a `metric` substring
- `(?!.*_(?:dk|none))` - that is not followed with any 0+ chars other than line break chars followed with `_` and then either `dk`  or `none`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EcMrG3/1).

NOTE: if you need to match only such values that contain `metric` and do not end with `_dk` or `_none`, use a variation, [`metric.*$(?<!_dk|_none)`](https://regex101.com/r/EcMrG3/2) where the `(?<!_dk|_none)` negative lookbehind fails the match if the string ends with either `_dk` or `_none`.

Comment: Two questions: can you explain what a PCRE pattern is? Not sure what the acronym even stands for. And, can you explain some of the notation in your regex like the parentheses, ?!, and so on? I'd love this to be a guide for others about lookahead negations.

Comment: @vashts85 PCRE stands for a Perl Compatible Regular Expression. See http://pcre.org. The answer won't become a guide as it would be too broad. You may learn [more about lookarounds at regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Here is an [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) about them.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this:

```
grep("^([[:alpha:]]+_){2}[[:alpha:]]+$", string, value = TRUE)
# [1] "business_metric_one" "business_metric_two"
```

or use `grepl` to match `dk` and `none`, then negate the logical when you're indexing the original `string`:

```
string[!grepl("(dk|none)", string)]
# [1] "business_metric_one" "business_metric_two"
```

more concisely:

```
string[!grepl("business_metric_[[:alpha:]]+_(dk|none)", string)]
# [1] "business_metric_one" "business_metric_two"
```

**Data:**

```
string = c("business_metric_one","business_metric_one_dk","business_metric_one_none","business_metric_two","business_metric_two_dk","business_metric_two_none")
```